# What's the time unit between two times?

Tags: python

```
import time
start = time.time()
diff = int((time.time() - start) * 1000)
```

The time() function 'Return the current time in seconds since the Epoch'. When two seconds subtract, what's the time unit of diff?

Comment: seconds - seconds => seconds, so `diff` in your code would be milliseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unit of measure is the same for both values, so the unit of measure after subtracting one value from another would still be seconds. However, since you're multiplying by 1000, the unit of measure for `diff` would be milliseconds (although this does not make `diff` any more precise).